# Mapreduce on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm very confused with the state and documentation of mapreduce support in GAE.

In the official doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/, there is an example, but :

- the application use mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreZipInputReader, and I would like to use **mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader**. The documentation mention the parameters of DatastoreInputReader, but not the **return value** sent back to the map fonction....
- the application "demo" (page Helloworld) has a **mapreduce.yaml** file wich **IS NOT USED** in the application ???

So I found http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/. The is a complete example with  **mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader**, but it is written that reduce phase isn't supported yet !

So I would like to know if it is possible to implement the first form of mapreduce, with the DatastoreInputReader, to execute a real map / reduce to get a GROUP BY equivalent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is from the earlier release, which did indeed just support the mapper phase. However, as the first example shows, the full map/reduce functionality is now supported and has been for some time. The mapreduce.yaml is from that earlier version, it is not used now.

I'm not sure what your actual question is. The value sent to the map function from DatastoreInputReader is, not surprisingly, the individual entity which is taken from the kind being mapped over.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my question. It's running now. It's a shame that the Google's official documentation points to an obsolete project without mention.. I tried to work on an outdated source code ... thanks again to put me on the good direction.